# Finding how many solutions a function has

Tags: roots

I have the function

$$f (x) = \cos x -  \frac{x^2}{100}$$

$$f'(x) = -\sin x \, -\frac{x}{50}$$

$$f''(x) = -\cos x - \frac{1}{50}$$

and I want to find out how many roots it has, I have tried using calculus and differentiating it. I have tried using Newton's method, and then realized it's not that helpful if I want to find HOW MANY instead of where the roots are.

Comment: You can use the mean value theorem to find the number of roots

Comment: @TheIntegrator thanks. Ill research what that is. I've seen you in one of my other posts yesterday, you sure are helpful

Comment: Happy to help. here are some links which might better explain it [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128833/finding-roots-of-a-function-with-mean-value-theorem), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128855/proving-roots-with-mean-value-theorem)

Comment: You can at least reduce the search space by noticing that any roots that exist must lie in $-10\le x\le 10$, since $-1\le \cos x \le 1$...